# Remove and/or redirect and append parameter with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, virtualhost

I am not very sure about the rewrite engine and the execution in some questions.
On a small project i have the following structure in www root:

```
root
  |- index.php      (file)
  |- sandbox.php    (file) 
  |- treehouse.php  (file)
  |- someother.php  (file)
  |- images         (folder)
  |   |- img1.jpg   (file)
  |   |- img2.jpg   (file)
  |   |- img3.jpg   (file)
  |- css            (folder)
  |   |- style.css  (file)  
  |- favicon.ico    (file)
```

With my rewrite rules I want to achieve the following:

1. https://example.com/index.php will be redirected to https://example.com/
2. for known php files (except index.php which is already redirected to / ) the php extention should be removed Instead of https://example.com/sandbox.php --> https://example.com/sandbox/
3. for few files/urls, parameterized urls should be work. eg for sandbox and treehouse. https://example.com/treehouse/magic/place/ should be translated into https://example.com/treehouse.php?param1=magic&param2=place
4. URLs should end with tailing /
5. all unknown files should be redirected to root https:

Well so far so good. I managed 1,2 and 5.
For 3 and 4 I need some input from the stack intelligence! I have tried it but always run in errors.
The working rule set is:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index(/|$) /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L,NC]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Redirect all not existing to root (index.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [R=301,L,QSA]
```

For experimenting, the rules are in a .htaccess file, later I plan to move them to the example.com.conf of the Apache web server.
I very appreciate any support to solve my issues as well any suggestions to improve my existing rules. Just because it works, doesn't mean I should do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have it this way:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove index
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index(\.php)?[\s?/] [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)index(/|$) /$1 [L,R=301,NC,NE]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/ [R=301,L]

# add trailing /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301,NE]

# 1 param rewrite
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param1=$2 [L,QSA]

# 2 param rewrite
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?param1=$2&param2=$3 [L,QSA]

# To internally redirect /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

# Redirect all not existing to root (index.php)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . / [R=301,L]
```

Comment: unfortunately... no :(

Comment: Please provide details what URLs didn't work and what error are you getting?

Comment: sorry for late feedback! have been off. Point #3 is not working if example.com/treehouse/tree should go to example.com/treehouse.php?param1=tree.  There have been some other issues that was my problem... means most the redirect works!

Comment: this works! Thousand Thanks! More and more I do understand this but... well my code caused tons of errors and frustration!